# Second order calculus and rough paths

Tags: stochastic-processes, smooth-manifolds, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations, rough-paths

In Emery's book "Stochastic calculus in manifolds", he shows how to make sense of integrals of the form
$$ \int \langle\Theta_t, \mathbf{d} X_t\rangle,$$
where $X$ is a semimartingale on a manifold $M$ and $\Theta$ is a predictable process above $X$ taking values in the second order tangent bundle $\tau M$ (the bundle of second order differential operators without constant term). See also ["An invitation to second order stochastic differential geometry"](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjdle2A3MjOAhXMaRQKHdAvCG4QFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhal.archives-ouvertes.fr%2Fhal-00145073%2Fdocument&usg=AFQjCNEg11Jr2VN6FSlhDe2BfSydrrtcvQ&sig2=899nYJzeP-ePYQXin630Og).

In the above, $\mathbf{d}X_t$ is the second order vector
$$\mathbf{d}X_t = dX^i_t D_i +\frac{1}{2}d [X^i_t, X^j_t] D_{ij},$$
the existence of which is "only metaphysical" (to speak with Emery's words) and the actual definition of the integral above does not use this "identity"; instead it is defined axiomatically.

Now I wonder: What is the relation of this to the theory of rough paths? In particular, can one make rigorous sense of $\mathbf{d}X_t$ as a covariant object using the theory of rough paths on a manifold, i.e. for a rough path, is its (second order?) infinitesimal increment somehow an element of the second order tangent bundle at a point? Can one then make sense *pathwise* of the integral above?

And what is actually a good covariant definition of a rough path on a manifold in this setting? I must admit that I have a hard time understanding rough paths in a covariant setting.